# retrieve caption of select from html form in servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have an html form with a list, like below

```
<select name="myselect">
   <option value="101">test val 1</option>
   <option value="102">test val 2</option>
   <option value="103">test val 3</option>
</select>
```

I am able to retrieve the option value in my servlet, using `getParameter()`
method

**But is there any way to get the caption of the selected option (ie. eg: test val 1)**

Answer (score 1):

**No.** But you can bind the caption to the value in html

```
<option value="101:test val 1">test val 1</option>
```

Now split from `:`

```
String value = request.getParameter("myselect");
String val1 = value.split(":")[0];
String val2 = value.split(":")[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this is a simple way and I'll try it until I get any other options (hope so).

Comment: Yeah it's the easiest way which I can think of. You r welcome :)

Comment: @muhammedaslam Don't forget to accept the answer if you decide to go with it ;)

Comment: I just found something here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp 

is there any way to retrieve the label attribute in servlet

Comment: No. Browser only sends the value of selected item not the label, it uses label just to display.

Answer (score 0):

as Roshana mentioned above, it is possible to bind the caption with the value. But it is difficult when there is a need to access options using js or ajax. So I found a similar solution which is to copy the selected value to an hidden field and access it from servlet.

```
<input type="hidden" id="selectCaption">
<select onchange="document.getElementById('selectCaption').value=this.text">
```

this doesn't change the value and gives no complications, and can simply access the value from servlet.